# Error en mi calculadora hecha con Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Adjunto mi codigo...

```
class Calculator extends React.Component {
 constructor() {
   super();
   this.state = {
     display: '0',
     formula: '',
   };

   this.handleNumberClick = this.handleNumberClick.bind(this);
   this.handleSignClick = this.handleSignClick.bind(this);
   this.handleEvaluate = this.handleEvaluate.bind(this);
   this.handleClear = this.handleClear.bind(this);
 }

 handleNumberClick = e => {
   const { display, formula } = this.state;
   const target = e.target.value;
   const newValue = display === '0' ? '' + target : display + '' + target;
   if (target === '.' && display.includes('.')) {
     return;
   }
   this.setState({
     formula: formula + '' + target,
     display: newValue,
   });
 };

 removeOperator = () => {
   let { formula } = this.state;
   while ('/-*+'.includes(formula.slice(-1))) {
     formula = formula.slice(0, -1);
   }
   return formula;
 };

 handleSignClick = e => {
   const { formula } = this.state;
   const target = e.target.value;
   let newFormula;
   if (target === '-') {
     newFormula = formula + '' + target;
   } else {
     newFormula = this.removeOperator() + '' + target;
   }
   this.setState({
     formula: newFormula,
     display: target,
   });
 };

 handleEvaluate = () => {
   const { formula } = this.state;
   const result = eval(formula);

   this.setState({
     display: result,
     formula: '' + result,
   });
 };

 handleClear = () => {
   this.setState({
     display: '0',
     formula: '',
   });
 };

 render() {
   const { display, formula } = this.state;
   return (
     <>
       <div className="container">
         <Display display={display} formula={formula} />

         <div className="container__btn__spaces">
           <NumberKey
             id="seven"
             handleClick={this.handleNumberClick}
             value={7}
           />

           <NumberKey
             id="eight"
             handleClick={this.handleNumberClick}
             value={8}
           />

           <NumberKey
             id="nine"
             handleClick={this.handleNumberClick}
             value={9}
           />

           <OperatorKey
             id="add"
             handleClick={this.handleSignClick}
             value="+"
           />

           <NumberKey
             id="four"
             handleClick={this.handleNumberClick}
             value={4}
           />

           <NumberKey
             id="five"
             handleClick={this.handleNumberClick}
             value={5}
           />

           <NumberKey
             id="six"
             handleClick={this.handleNumberClick}
             value={6}
           />

           <OperatorKey
             id="subtract"
             handleClick={this.handleSignClick}
             value="-"
           />

           <NumberKey
             id="one"
             handleClick={this.handleNumberClick}
             value={1}
           />

           <NumberKey
             id="two"
             handleClick={this.handleNumberClick}
             value={2}
           />

           <NumberKey
             id="three"
             handleClick={this.handleNumberClick}
             value={3}
           />

           <OperatorKey
             id="divide"
             handleClick={this.handleSignClick}
             value="/"
           />

           <NumberKey
             id="zero"
             handleClick={this.handleNumberClick}
             value={0}
           />

           <NumberKey
             id="decimal"
             handleClick={this.handleNumberClick}
             value="."
           />
           <button
             className="container__btn container__btn--clear"
             id="clear"
             onClick={this.handleClear}
           >
             C
           </button>
           <OperatorKey
             id="multiply"
             handleClick={this.handleSignClick}
             value="*"
           />
         </div>
         <button
           className="container__btn container__btn--equal"
           id="equals"
           onClick={this.handleEvaluate}
         >
           =
         </button>
       </div>
     </>
   );
 }
}

const Display = props => {
 const { display, formula } = props;
 return (
   <>
     <div className="container__display">
       <div className="container__display--outputs">{formula} </div>
       <hr className="container__display--space" />
       <div
         className="container__display--outputs container__display--outputs--formula"
         id="display"
       >
         {display}
       </div>
     </div>
   </>
 );
};

const OperatorKey = props => {
 const { value, id, handleClick } = props;
 return (
   <button
     className="container__btn container__btn--operators"
     id={id}
     value={value}
     onClick={handleClick}
   >
     {value}
   </button>
 );
};

const NumberKey = props => {
 const { value, id, handleClick } = props;
 return (
   <button
     className="container__btn"
     id={id}
     value={value}
     onClick={handleClick}
   >
     {value}
   </button>
 );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Calculator />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Tengo varios errores en mi calculadora.

1. Al realizar cualquier operación sea "[+,-,*,/]" con un "." me arroja el siguiente error en la consola -> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
2. El segundo error es que al terminar una operación al hacer click en cualquier numero se le adiciona a mis items del display (formula y display), ¿Que podria implementar de manera de que al mandar un nuevo numero mi display se reinicie y se obtenga ese nuevo valor?.

Actualmente estoy realizando esas modificaciónes en un **Pen** de prueba en CodePen..

Adjunto enlace..

[TestCalculator](https://codepen.io/luismgil/full/bGwzOwM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El primer error no consigo reproducirlo en el CodePen, hago operaciones con decimales y no veo que salte ningún error en la consola.

El segundo error, lo puedes solucionar con un `bool` controlando si has acabado la operación o no:

```
this.state = {
     display: '0',
     formula: '',
     cleared: false
 };
```

En el `handleEvaluate`:

```
this.setState({
  display: result,
  formula: '' + result,
  cleared: true
});
```

Y tanto en el `handleNumberClick`, como en el `handleSignClick`:

```
const { display, formula,cleared } = this.state;
```

Donde seteas el state:

```
this.setState({
      formula: cleared ? target : formula + '' + target,
      display: cleared ? target : newValue,
      cleared:false
    });
```

Comment: Excelente, me ha funcionado! Y respecto al primer problema creo que lo puedo solucionar facilmente manejando el error en un mensaje, es algo que no deberia ocurrir solo que la calculadora deja de funcionar sin ningun tipo de aviso.